# Failed 14.04.5 to 16.04 upgrade - left with 159 pkgs to autoremove, 269 held back. What to do?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management

Recently, I tried to upgrade Ubuntu from 14.04.5 to 16.04 by clicking Software Updater's box. As the installation was proceeding, it popped up a "14.04 system error" window, I clicked "Report", and immediately got a "16.04 system error" window. I clicked "Report" and got a locked screen. When I unlocked it, the update had ended. I rebooted, and the system was strange. I meddled with it, noticing problems with the `sa-compile` package. Since I don't need `Tools for compiling SpamAssassin rules into C` on this system, I `apt-get remove --purge`'d it. End of introductory tale.

As a result of a medded-with failed upgrade from 14.04.5 to 16.04, I'm left with `apt-get` telling me I have 159 packages to `autoremove`, and 269 `held back`.

As I see it, I have several choices (after I backup `/home`):

1. Download a 16.04 ISO, start over.
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove` and hope that I'm left with a runnable system to install the `held back` packages.
3. Ignore the `autoremove` for now, and run `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests --fix-broken --ignore-hold --with-new-pkgs --reinstall` on the `held back` packages.
4. Other?

Suggestions, requests for more data, ... ? I do have `ssh` access, as well as physical access.

Comment: Just a side note: I recommend placing home on it's own partition. that along with creating a forensic image of the original OS  makes recovering from these unintended consequences much simpler

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek: `/home` is a separate partition, but having a backup guards against typos/mindos when performing surgery with blunt tools.

Comment: ;-) Well said.... Reviewing the list of held packages and those to auto-remove with an eye toward criticality might help you in the decision making process. I would hesitate to provide a "just do this" answer as I'm assuming that you know a great deal more about critical applications on your system than I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With advice from @elder-geek: I reinspected the list of packages to be `autoremove`d, and used

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run autoremove
```

as a final check, to make sure I wasn't about to `autoremove` the world.

I ended up doing:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Checking statuses, logs, the happiness of the packaging system, any anything else I could think of between each pair of steps.

That system hasn't fallen over or misbehaved yet, and is lightly (due to my testing laziness) useable, so I'll declare this upgrade a success.